# getrawmempool verbose returns ambiguous results

Tags: json-rpc, transaction-weight

bitcoind v0.15.1 `getrawmempool` rpc in verbose mode returns `size` and `vsize` for a transaction:

`vsize`: size for fees post-segwit (ceil(weight/4))

`size`: disksize

But getrawmempool rcp also returns `descendantsize` and `ancestorsize` values.

Are these values segwit-aware? do they return the ancestor/descendant transaction disksize sum or ancestor/descendant vsize sum?

Answer (score 1):

As easy as read an actual rpc call instead of bitcoin.org documentation:

"descendantsize" : n,   (numeric) **virtual transaction size** of in-mempool descendants (including this one)
"ancestorsize" : n,     (numeric) **virtual transaction size** of in-mempool ancestors (including this one)strong text